# RenderDelegate not being called

Tags: c#, winforms, objectlistview

I have set up a `RenderDelegate` to draw the cell text in a different color. I have also set the `OwnerDraw` property to `true`.

This is the render code:

```
this.olvInvoiceType.RendererDelegate = delegate (EventArgs re, Graphics g, Rectangle r, object rowObject)
{
    var item= rowObject as MyItem;
    var brush = Brushes.Red;

    g.DrawString(item.Name, olvItems.Font, brush, r);
    return false;
};
```

However, nothing is being displayed.

What am I missing?

Comment: @IvanKishchenko Winforms. `olvInvoiceType` is the standard `OLVColumn`

Answer (score 0):

Despite what the example on the ObjectListView website says it seems that you actually have to return true, and not false.

Other examples I found also return true.

Also, don't forget to check that your object is null before rendering, else it will throw an exception!

```
this.olvInvoiceType.RendererDelegate =  delegate (EventArgs re, Graphics g, Rectangle r, object rowObject)
            {
                var item = rowObject as MyItem;
                if (item != null)
                {
                    //g.FillRectangle(new SolidBrush(this.olvItems.BackColor), r);
                    g.DrawString(item.Name, olvItems.Font, brush, r);
                }
               return true;
            };
```

When I tried this I seemed to have the strange issue that the text was rendered twice, once originally by the control in black and then another time by me in red!
This might be a bug, or I might have missed something.

To get around this then I had to paint the background will fillrectangele, but then you have the issue if the row in selected so you would need to handle this separately.

I also found that OwnerDraw made no difference!

Comment: Your text is being drawn twice is because you're return true when you should return false.

Comment: But if I return false then the delegate does nothing!

Answer (score 0):

I know it's an old question, but I had the same problem and couldn't find any correct answers. I'll leave my answer, maybe it helps somebody.

`nameColumn.RendererDelegate` is not called no matter what I do or which OwnerRender mode I'm in.

`nameColumn.Renderer = SomeCustomIRenderer` is also not called completely no matter what I do.

I managed to fix the issue by adding:

`treeListView.CellRendererGetter = (object rowObject, OLVColumn column) => new MyCustomIRenderer();` And only after that, my custom renderer was actually called.

Easiest way is to override your own BaseRenderer or just copy one from here http://objectlistview.sourceforge.net/cs/ownerDraw.html#owner-draw-label